# What should I claim on tax withholding?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction

I currently just graduated and received a job! Wahoo! My Dad told me he is still going to claim me though, for this year anyways. First question is: What does that really mean? Also, should I claim a 1 or a 2. I would like the most money I could get right away without having to pay in. Does him claiming me make me get less money back? I am only 21 years old and went to school for the first semester of the year.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're in the USA, here goes:

In 2018, this is a very different boat than in 2017 and before.  Before, there was a personal exemption of $4000 that you didn't get if someone else claimed you, and instead they got you.

But in 2018, that doesn't exist - so your dad is wrong.  He won't claim you, because there's no exemption to claim.  (See for example [this article](https://www.romper.com/p/will-claiming-dependents-change-under-the-new-tax-bill-taxes-could-get-higher-for-parents-7702735).)

Ultimately, you are best served filling out the W4 according to the [instructions](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/fw4--2018.pdf) for your first year.  Then figure out at tax time *next* year if you're over-withholding or under, and adjust accordingly.

My guess is you'll enter a '2', if you're single and have one job and no kids.

Comment: N.b.: Odds are your dad couldn't have claimed you, anyway; the cap for *your* earnings was $4000.  If you're earning over $4000,  you aren't eligible to be claimed.  Further, if you are over 19 and no longer a student, you're not eligible to be claimed, though if you were a student *part* of the year, maybe. But I'd hope you're making over $4000 in the second half of the year...

Comment: It might also affect the Earned Income Tax Credit.