# Will I be able to be claimed or not?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I currently graduated from college in May and have been working since January. My father believe he will be able to claim me, but after reading what people said in the post [in this link](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/96180/what-should-i-claim-on-tax-withholding) I dont believe he will be. Would someone be able to clarify with me whether or not he will be able to claim me since I was in College for 4 months out of the year? Some other facts that might come into play, I have been renting for over a year now, don't live at home. Am 21 years old. Current home address is set as my fathers place.

Answer (score 4):

In general, your father can only claim you as a dependent if he paid at least 50% of your living costs for the year. Since you have graduated college (congrats!) and have been on your own for a while, most likely he has not.

See [this link](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p501#en_US_2017_publink1000220868) (from IRS Pub 501) for more info. The rules are for 2017 (I couldn't find them for 2018), but they should still apply.

You should also probably update your address to reflect your actual address when you send in your tax return.

Comment: As correctly stated in the linked Q, the RULES DO CHANGE FOR 2018 (through 2025 unless amended again, as may well happen). All personal exemptions (self, spouse and dependent) are eliminated, while the standard deduction and child tax credit are increased. OP's father here doesn't qualify for CTC -- and couldn't have gotten an exemption under the old rules anyway: OP is over 19 and no longer a student. PS: most 2018 forms&pubs won't come out until near the end of the year, but 1040es (Estimated Tax) is out and contains a summary of the changes.